# Related Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I recently came across this fascinating problem online:

Let $\displaystyle g_1(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g(t)\, dt,\: \: g_2(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g_1(t)\, dt,..., \: \: g_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g_{n-1}(t)\, dt$

Prove that $(n-1)!g_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{n-1}g(t)\, dt $

I achieved the result by repeated integration by parts, but it was a little messy. I was wondering if there is a neater way of achieving this result, and whether we can use it to deduce further interesting results, since the problem seems a little short.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you let $g_i$ for $i=n-1, \dots ,1$ be the $v'$ in the integration by parts? $$ \int uv' \text{ d}t = uv - \int v u' \text{ d}t $$

Comment: Yes, thats the way I did it. It should express the repeated integrals as just one integral in the end (which is the result). But can you think of any extensions to the question? I'd maybe consider using it on a problem solving worksheet

Comment: I don't see how to get past the initial stage concerning the indefinite integrals under the limits. $$ \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1} g(t) \text{ d}t = \left[ \left(x-t\right)^{n-1} \int g(t) \text{ d}t \right]_{0}^{x} + (n-1) \int_{0}^{x} \left( (x-t)^{n-2} \int g(t) \text{ d}t \right) \text{ d}t $$

Comment: I didn't work backwards like you have. I started from the last term: $\displaystyle g_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g_{n-1}(t) \, dt$. But remember that $\displaystyle g_{n-1}(t) = \int_{0}^{t}g_{n-2}(t) \, dt$ so we end up with a 'nested' integration. I then chose $u$ in the parts formula to be $g_{n-1}(t)$ and differentiated the integral with respect to $t$ to get $u^\prime$ (meaning 1 was used for $v^\prime$) and repeated the parts process to get the result

Comment: Oh, ok! Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you think of any extensions to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26768/discussion-between-wrb98-and-khallil).